# get all immediate child elements with a given tag name? Native JS only

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

No JQuery please.

I'm quite surprised not to have found the answer to this. I'll probably be "duped".

The problem is to get only the **immediate** child elements with a given tag name (e.g. DIV), so `getElementsByTagName` doesn't work: this will return all descendants with that tag name.

There's a nice-looking answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23335484/595305), using `querySelectorAll()`:

```
const childDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#xyz > div');
```

... but what I've done is just create an element (DIV) on the fly and made its `innerHTML` equal to the content of a `fetch`'d HTML file. The consequence of this is to make the BODY's child elements become the child elements of the created element.

So it doesn't have an ID or class, and it's not even in the DOM tree. Of course I can iterate ... but who wants to iterate in 2020! Preposterous. So how might I say:

```
const childDivs = container.querySelectorAll('ME > DIV');
```

...?

**Edit**

Had a go with the `filter` idea from Barmer:

```
const childEls = container.children
function checkDiv( el ){
    return el.tagName === 'DIV'
}
const childDivs = childEls.filter( checkDiv )
```

error: "childEls.filter is not a function"

... I think `childEls` (class [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) above is one of those "Array-like" objects. So I believe you have to do this:

```
const childEls = container.children
const newArr = Array.prototype.slice.call( childEls );
const childDivs = newArr.filter( function( el ){ return el.tagName === 'DIV' }  )
```

... which works... but is, in truth, iteration. Boo.

Comment: Isn't it just `el.children()` where `el` is the element you just created?

Comment: Er... that would return all child elements, regardless of tag name. I'd then have to iterate through that list. I may **have** to iterate through that list!

Comment: I didn't realize "of a given tag name" referred to the elements you were looking for, I thiought that was what you were getting the children of.

Comment: Get all the children and then call `filter()` to check the tag name.

Comment: Aha... just tried to clear up possible lack of clarity on my part.

Comment: No familiarity with `filter` ... just looked it up. Thanks for that. So  no way I can use a selector... ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a selector because there's no way to specify the top-level element, so you can't select only its immediate children. In the DOM you do it with the `body` selector, but there's nothing analogous in your anonymous element.

Comment: Does it has other childs also other than div?

Comment: @AnkitChaudhary ... yes, other elements and possibly other non-element nodes... otherwise the problem would not arise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**A NON IE solution:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility)

Using `:scope` pseudo class

> The :scope CSS pseudo-class represents elements that are a reference
>   point for selectors to match against.

```
const childDivs = container.querySelectorAll(':scope > div')
```

**An IE solution:**

We need to make the `HTMLCollection` object the scope of `Array.prototype.filter` to filter `HTMLCollection` object. That can be achieved by `call`,`apply` or `bind`.

**Using Call:**

```
const childDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(childEls,checkDiv );
```

**Using Apply:**

```
const childDivs = Array.prototype.filter.apply(childEls,[checkDiv] );
```

**Using Bind:**

```
const childDivs = Array.prototype.filter.bind(childEls)(checkDiv);
```

Comment: Well done. I had a feeling there was something along those lines. `call`, right. Whether it has any advantage over a simple iteration, however... :-)

Comment: not a big advantage ....just more short and readable code :). Filter works over iteration only.

Comment: @mikerodent you can use `:scope`. If you don't support IE

Comment: That's great. Who'd have thought that in 2020 IE would be the one browser unable to adopt sensible CSS standards (irony). Edge, however, does have this.